# Auto relación Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, relaciones

Les comento, tengo una colección de usuarios donde tengo un campo **creadoPor** para guardar el id y hacer referencia al usuario que lo creo, lo que pasa es que el primer usuario que se registra se crea así mismo. Se puede en mongo hacer auto relaciones ?

Schema:

```js
var usuarioSchema = new Schema({
    // Info usuario

    nombres: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'] },
    apellidos: { type: String, required: [true, 'El apellido es necesario'] },
    cedula: { type: String, unique: [true, 'Este número de cedula ya se encuentra registrado'], required: [true, 'La decula es necesaria'] },
    telefono: { type: String, required: [true, 'El telefono es necesario'] },
    correo: { type: String, unique: [true, 'Este correo ya se encuentra registrado'], required: [true, 'El correo electronico es necesario'] },
    contrasena: { type: String, required: [true, 'La contraseña es necesaria'] },
    cargo: { type: String, default: 'Representante legal', required: [true, 'El cargo es necesario'] },
    rol: {},
    imagen: { type: String, default: 'user.png' },
    activo: { type: Boolean, default: true },


    // referencias

    creadoPor: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario',
    },
    empresa: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Empresa',
        required: [true, 'El id empresa es un campo obligatorio ']
    },
    menu: []
}, { timestamps: true });`
```

Comment: ¿Podrías al menos añadir el código de tu esquema? Sería de utilidad de cara a una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Listo agregado el schema, no se que tan buena practica sea, pero al momento de crear un usuario con moongose, al llenar el modelo, por ejemplo, var usuario = new Usuario({ Información }) y hacerle un console.log(usuario) me encontre que el _id se crea en ese momento, entonces lo que hice fue poner usuario.creadoPor = usuario._id y hasta el momento me ha funcionando y se hace una auto referencia al documento. No se que tan buena practica sea o si pueda haber algún tipo de conflicto.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB es una base de datos no relacional, por tanto **NO CUENTA CON RELACIONES** como si lo hay en bases de datos relacionales como MySQL o PostgreSQL. Lo que si puedes usar son referencias a objetos en otras colecciones (o en la misma colección), pero no estarán "enlazados".

En el caso especifico que comentas, puedes dejar el campo `creadoPor` en null cuando lo creas y cuando ya este creado actualizas el campo `creadoPor` con el campo `_id` del documento.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear una referencia a la misma colección a la que pertenece un documento, de tal manera que el campo `creadoPor` apunte a un campo `_id` de otro documento o que apunte al campo `_id` del mismo documento. El segundo caso ocurre cuando el documento es auto creado (en la pregunta el OP indica que sus documentos pertenecen a la colección de usuarios, por lo tanto se espera que *el primer usuario que se registra, se crea a sí mismo*).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, podemos usar la propiedad [`default`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) en el campo `creadoPor`, acompañada de una [función](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions) (explícita) que devolverá el valor del `_id` de la instancia del modelo que se está creando, usando la palabra reservada [`this`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions-and-this).

El campo debes escribirlo así:

```js
creadoPor: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Usuario',
  default: function() {
    return this._id;
  }
},
```

Como puedes observar al campo `creadoPor` le hemos añadido un atributo llamado `default`, el cual es una función que devuelve el campo `_id` del objeto `this`.

Cuando creas una instancia del modelo, si el campo `creadoPor` es `undefined`, se llamará a la función del campo `default` y la misma devolverá el valor del `_id` del modelo que se está creando.

Otra solución (sin usar el atributo `default`) sería crear una instancia del modelo, tal como lo tienes actualmente, pero antes de salvar el mismo establecer el campo `creadoPor`, usando una lógica de comparación para saber si el mismo es `undefined` o no.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que los documentos los creas a partir de tu Modelo de la siguiente forma:

```js
const newUser = new Usuario(req.body);

//verificamos si el campo `creadoPor` no existe para añadir su valor
if(!newUser.creadoPor) {
  newUser.creadoPor = newUser._id;
}

console.log(newUser);

// newUser.save() ...
```

De esta forma, también estamos creando una referencia al mismo usuario, sin embargo tal vez más intuitivo hacerlo usando el atributo `default`.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo.